# XPCOM and firefox mobile

Tags: android, c++, firefox, mobile, xpcom

I found a lot of problems in order to develop a browser plugin for android..
I've to use several C++ libraries and so I need to write C++ code.

Can I develop a firefox mobile extension with C++ XPCOM core?

if yes --Where can I find some examples?

Thanks a lot for your support
Mauro